# Unable to authenticate using Apache and authnz_mod_ldap in Active Directory

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, ldap, debian-squeeze

I have a problem with `Apache2` authentication using `authnz_ldap_module` in order to authenticate users from `Active Directory`.
My Apache version is `2.2.16-6+squeeze10`.

Here is the configuration I am trying to use with no luck (one of many combinations, to be precise):

```
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Active Directory"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://server1.my.company.tld:3268 server2.my.company.tld:3268/dc=my,dc=company,dc=tld?sAMAccountName?sub"
AuthLDAPBindDN "uid=my_user,dc=my,dc=company,dc=tld"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "mypassword"
Require valid-user
```

And I get following entries in Apache's `error.log`:

```
[debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(379): [client some_ip_here] [12391] auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://server1.my.company.tld:3268 server2.my.company.tld:3268/dc=my,dc=company,dc=tld?sAMAccountName?sub
[info] [client some_ip_here] [12391] auth_ldap authenticate: user my_user authentication failed; URI / [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed][Invalid credentials]
[error] [client some_ip_here] user my_user: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
```

Of course I enter correct password each time, I would get blocked in AD about hundred times already, didn't happen single time so far.

I cannot verify, that I can connect to my AD controller, because when I try:

```
ldapsearch -h server1.my.company.tld -p 3268 -D "dc=my,dc=company,dc=tld"
```

I get following error:

```
text: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1
```

I have absolutely no idea how to bind with `ldapsearch` and manual didn't help me so far.

What am I doing wrong with `Apache2`  configuration and how can I bind with `ldapsearch`?

I will provide additional information, if these are needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most problematic case was AuthLDAPBindDN, which had to be in syntax of "user@my.company.tld" and not of syntax "domain\user" neither simply "user" nor "uid=my_user,dc=my,dc=company,dc=tld".
Below is the proper configuration that did work for me, which I provide here as solution for the case.

```
            AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
            AuthBasicProvider ldap
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Active Directory"
            AuthLDAPURL "ldap://server1.my.company.tld:3268 server2.my.company.tld:3268/DC=ad,DC=upos,DC=pl?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
            AuthLDAPBindDN "bind_user@my.company.tld"
            AuthLDAPBindPassword "some_random_password"
            Require valid-user
```

It has taken me long time to provide the answer, what I am sorry for.

Comment: This did the trick for me too. Bizarre!

Comment: Found this answer while googling, worked for me too :) (apache 2.4, on windows server 2008)

Comment: what about `DOMAIN\USER` authentication ?

Comment: @VarunChandak could you clarify your question?

Comment: @tymik for `AuthLDAPBindDN` entry, what if I want to use `DOMAIN\USER` instead of `user@domain` ?

Comment: as my post states, you cannot - at least you couldn't at the time when I wrote that answer. the answer is to guide you how you have (or had in past) to set it up.

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell ldapsearch who you are binding *as* so, per ldapsearch --help, use the -U switch and give it a user name... i.e.

```
ldapsearch -h server1.my.company.tld -p 3268 -D "dc=my,dc=company,dc=tld" -U <username>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, I don't know why, but couldn't find it on my own.
Now I know more about what might cause problem with `APACHE`, but still got no solution.